# NCO: Copying data from one netcdf file into another only for a specific area

Tags: replace, nco

I have two NetCDF files with the exact same dimensions (time,lat,lon). Below is the header of one of the files.

```
netcdf file1 {
dimensions:
        lon = 360 ;
        lat = 177 ;
        time = 360 ;
variables:
        double lon(lon) ;
                lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
                lon:long_name = "Longitude" ;
        double lat(lat) ;
                lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
                lat:long_name = "Latitude" ;
        double time(time) ;
                time:long_name = "Time" ;
                time:units = "months since 1989-05-01 00:00" ;
        double tmp(time, lat, lon) ;
                tmp:_FillValue = -999000000. ;
}
```

I would like to copy values from one file into the other, but only for a small region determined by lat1,lat2 and lon1,lon2. Both files have the same time coordinates.

Something like: `(lon1<lon<=lon2) & (lat1<lat<=lat2) file1 = file2`

I was wondering if I could do that with NCO.

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank

Answer (score 2):

Read the [manual](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#where) section on the `ncap2` `where` function. It describes how to use where on a hyperslab. That will do it:

```
*var_tmp=var2(:,0,:,:); 
where (var1 < 0.5) var_tmp=1234; 
var2(;,0,:,;)=var_tmp;
```

Comment: Thank you, Charlie for answering my question.  So for your suggestion to work i would need to combine both file1 and file2 into one third file, and change one of the variables name in that 3rd file.  Right?